# What can i use instead of a model for settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails app i created an extra model for settings. Im wondering if there is anything better to safe the settings! The thing is that settings represent one instance of this model! I considerd to safe my settings to a yaml file but the probem is that then i cannot easily call them in my controllers? What would you suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're talking about application based settings? If so we use the application's config file to put global settings. The config looks like this:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
Application.configure do
  config.setting = true
end
```

You can access the setting via:

```
Rails.application.config.setting
```

The nice bit about this is that you can do settings based on each individual environment.

Comment: In my settings i want to safe for example `street of programmer, name of programmer, relaese etc` I dont know if the config settings are the right place for something like this? What would you say? Thanks

Comment: You can put it in a Helper, or directly in your Views too. Just depends on how often you're accessing/changing it...

Comment: Good point! The thing is i want be able to edit them on a adminpage!

Comment: Then that means database storage and doing the settings in a model